# apt packages gnome-shell switched to now and does not update

Tags: apt, gnome-shell, repository

This morning there was an update for gnome-shell on my 22.04 notebook and I updated it. On my 22.04 desktop PC this update was not listed. I recognized that on my notebook when I run `apt list gnome-shell -a` the output is:

```
gnome-shell/jammy-updates 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-shell/jammy 42.0-2ubuntu1 amd64
```

On my Desktop it is:

```
gnome-shell/jammy-updates 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 amd64
gnome-shell/now 42.1-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed,local]
gnome-shell/jammy 42.0-2ubuntu1 amd64
```

I can't update this package on my Desktop. Are there any automatic updates in 22.04 that can switch package sources? And how to update this package now if it doesn't have the right channel?

Comment: can you not do `apt update` and `apt upgrade`?

Comment: No, it says no updates available.

Comment: I thought it's something like that. Was it introduced in 21.04? That explain, why I have never seen this before. Just recently updated from 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remain calm.

Looks like plain old [Phased Updates](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/phased-updates-in-apt-in-21-04/20345) to me. Simply be patient for a couple days, and phasing will catch up to your Desktop.

- How to verify that it's Phased Updates: Run `apt-cache policy <package_name>`. If phasing is going on, it's clearly listed.

Example:

```
$ apt-cache policy gnome-shell
gnome-shell:
  Installed: 42.1-0ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 42.1-0ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
     42.2-0ubuntu0.2 1 (phased 30%)   <------- There it is in plain view
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 42.1-0ubuntu0.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     42.0-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

- Phased Updates have already been around for a decade when using the Ubuntu Software/Software Store applications or Update Manger or most other Desktop-based (aptdaemon) tools. Phased updates are **new** to the apt command in 22.04 -- it's in the [Release Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668). Most people never notice it (that's the idea).
- DON'T try to cleverly outwit Phased Updates. It's there to help protect you. Be patient. Let it work. Folks who have a real need (like testers) to disable Phased Updates can do so quite easily.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer. Yes, it is Phased (40%). I just don't see, how this can protect me, if my notebook already got the update running the almost exact same system. I like to keep my systems "in sync" with package versions. Is there still a way to do that?

Comment: For "protection," review where this update is coming from: jammy-updates, not jammy-security. It's a bugfix, not a CVE patch.  For keeping multiple systems in sync, read the documentation.